# How to filter IOT messages from different devices in azure function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I have created one [IOT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-java) in Azure and added two devices in that. I am sending same message from both of the device. I have also created one [function app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal) in Azure. The function is triggering with Azure IoT Hub and it saving data to azure storage table. All things are working as per expectation. Now I want to filter message using device id. I meant my azure function app should recognize the message is came from which device.

Here is my function app java script code

```
module.exports = function (context, iotHubMessage) {

context.log(iotHubMessage.length + ' Message received');

var date = Date.now();
var partitionKey = Math.floor(date / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) + '';
var rowKey = date;

context.bindings.messageLog1 = {
    "partitionKey": partitionKey,
    "rowKey": rowKey + '',
    "MsgCount": iotHubMessage.length,
    "data": JSON.stringify(iotHubMessage)
};

var defaultData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < iotHubMessage.length; i++) {

    var iotMsgObj = iotHubMessage[i];

    iotMsgObj.CreatedDate = new Date();

    defaultData.push({ "partitionKey": partitionKey, "rowKey": (rowKey+i) + '', "data": JSON.stringify(iotMsgObj) });
}

context.bindings.pbDefaultPara1 = defaultData;

context.done();
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jignesh, have you tried my solution? Is it working for you?

Answer (score 1):

In **JavaScript**, you can use the following method to get the device id:

```
context.bindingData.systemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"]
```

The index.js looks like this:

```
    module.exports = function (context, IoTHubMessages) {
    context.log('systemProperties', context.bindingData.systemProperties, 'of type', (typeof context.bindingData.systemProperties));
    context.log('DeviceId: ', context.bindingData.systemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"]);
    context.done();
};
```

The log is:

```
2018-07-18T08:55:17.122 [Info] systemProperties { 'iothub-connection-device-id': 'device1',
  'iothub-connection-auth-method': '{"scope":"device","type":"sas","issuer":"iothub","acceptingIpFilterRule":null}',
  'iothub-connection-auth-generation-id': '636627421237258770',
  'iothub-enqueuedtime': 2018-07-18T08:55:16.193Z,
  'iothub-message-source': 'Telemetry',
  'x-opt-sequence-number': 48574,
  'x-opt-offset': '28334352',
  'x-opt-enqueued-time': 2018-07-18T08:55:17.100Z,
  enqueuedTimeUtc: 2018-07-18T08:55:17.100Z,
  sequenceNumber: 48574,
  offset: '28334352',
  'content-type': 'JSON' } of type object
2018-07-18T08:55:17.122 [Info] DeviceId:  device1
2018-07-18T08:55:17.122 [Info] Function completed (Success, Id=709739ed-7b14-4ac2-821f-df2a68c601ef, Duration=2ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the c#:

```
using System;

public static void Run(string myIoTHubMessage, IDictionary<string, object> properties, IDictionary<string, object> systemproperties, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: \n\t{myIoTHubMessage}");

    log.Info($"\nSystemProperties:\n\t{string.Join("\n\t", systemproperties.Select(i => $"{i.Key}={i.Value}"))}");

    log.Info($"\nProperties:\n\t{string.Join("\n\t", properties.Select(i => $"{i.Key}={i.Value}"))}");
}
```

and the telemetry sample in the Log:

```
    2018-07-17T14:34:32.521 [Info] C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: 
        {"counter":0,"time":"2018-07-17T14:34:31.9949651Z","deviceId":"Device02","windSpeed":11.9509,"temperature":16.58,"humidity":79.94}
    2018-07-17T14:34:32.521 [Info] SystemProperties:
        iothub-connection-device-id=Device02
        iothub-connection-auth-method=   {"scope":"device","type":"sas","issuer":"iothub","acceptingIpFilterRule":null}
        iothub-connection-auth-generation-id=636652663042146012
        iothub-enqueuedtime=7/17/2018 2:34:31 PM
        iothub-message-source=Telemetry
        x-opt-sequence-number=1542
        x-opt-offset=769928
        x-opt-enqueued-time=7/17/2018 2:34:32 PM
        EnqueuedTimeUtc=7/17/2018 2:34:32 PM
        SequenceNumber=1542
        Offset=769928
    2018-07-17T14:34:32.521 [Info] Properties:
    2018-07-17T14:34:32.521 [Info] Function completed (Success, Id=24df604d-40a4-4509-8631-ddaba9f56d4b, Duration=242ms)
```

as you can see the above Log, the deviceId is in the SystemProperties.